# Is Skellam distribution or difference of two independent identical Poisson random variable sub-gaussain?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

I have some question about the difference between two iid Poisson random variables. Given $X,Y \sim Poi(\chi)$ are two iid random variables. We know that $Z=X-Y$ follows from a Skellam distribution. Then, I have a question about the concentration of $Z$. Is there any way we can show $Z$ is sub-gaussian or disprove it? Does anyone have any idea or hint?

Thank you in advance!

P.S. The definition of being sub-gaussian follows from the textbook by

Vershynin, R., 2018. High-dimensional probability: An introduction with applications in data science (Vol. 47). Cambridge university press.

Comment: One way to characterize subgaussians is an upper bound on the growth of the moments. Since Poissons are not subgaussian, one can deduce, using independence, that $Z$ is not subgaussian.